# Isomorphism of $F$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $K/F$ be a field extension, and consider $R=F[x]/(g(x))$ for some $g\in F[x]$. Then $R$ is an $F$-vector space and an $F$-algebra. Further, $K\otimes_F R$ is an $F$-algebra. I'd like to show that $K\otimes_F R$ is isomorphic to $K[x]/(g(x))$ as an $F$-algebra.

To do this, I start by using the universal property for tensor products. Consider the map $\varphi:K\times R\rightarrow K[x]/(g(x))$ given by $\varphi(k,f(x)+(g(x)))=kf(x)+(g(x))$. This is an $F$-bilinear map, and by the universal property, this induces an $F$-module homomorphism $\Phi:K\otimes_F R\rightarrow K[x]/(g(x))$, where $\varphi=\Phi\circ\iota$, and where $\iota :K\times R\rightarrow K\otimes_F R$ is the natural map.

Now, it is not hard to see that this map is surjective: since the image of $\varphi$ generates $K[x]/(g(x))$ as an abelian group, we get that $\varphi$ is surjective and so $\Phi$ is  surjective as well.

My problem lies in trying to show that $\Phi$ is an injective $F$-module homomorphism, and that it also preserves multiplication. How do I go about doing this? Do I need to construct a map from $K[x]/(g(x))$ to $K\otimes_F R$? Is this even possible?

Comment: K is an extension of F. $g$ has coefficients in $K$ as well.

Comment: You're correct! I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to approach the problem.

One could use the fact the morphism $\Phi$ is $K$-linear and prove that the $K$-spaces $K \otimes_F R$ and $K[x]/(g(x))$ have the same dimensions.

Nevertheless I prefer a more direct approach that proves an inverse for $\Phi$.

We start by building a mapping $\iota' \colon K[x] \to K \otimes_F R$ defined by 
$$\iota'(\sum_n a_n x^n) = \sum_n a_n \otimes (x^n + (g(x)))$$ 
which can be proven to be a $F$-linear map (indeed it is a $K$-linear map) whose kernel contain $g(x)$.

Hence by the universal property of quotients it follows that this map factors through a unique $\iota \colon K[x]/(g(x)) \to K \otimes_F R$, which is the map such that 
$$\iota(\sum_n a_n x^n + (g(x)))=\sum_n a_n \otimes (x^n+(g(x)))\ .$$

An easy computation shows us that 
$$\iota\circ\Phi(\lambda \otimes (x^n+(g(x))))=\iota(\lambda x^n +(g(x)))=\lambda \otimes (x^n+(g(x)))$$
that is $\iota\circ\Phi$ coincides with the identity on a set of generators for $K\otimes_F R$. From this it follows that $\iota\circ\Phi=\text{id}$, hence the injectivity of $\Phi$ (similarly one can prove that $\Phi \circ \iota = \text{id}$).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does this then show that they are isomorphic as rings as well? Don't we need multiplication preserved?

Comment: @ponchan well this proves that $\Phi$ is bijective, hence that it is an isomorphisms. Anyway it is a general fact, I assumed you knew, that the inverse function to a bijective homomorphism is itself an homomorphism.

Comment: Again, when you say "homomorphism", it's not clear whether you are referring to the module homomorphism, or the ring homomorphism. A module homomorphism must only preserve the addition of the underlying abelian group and the R (in this case F) action. To show that they are also isomorphic as $F$-algebras, it is necessary to show that they are isomorphic as rings, meaning that the multiplicative operation is preserved. I'm not sure how your argument does this.

Comment: I have left voluntarily unspecified the structure considered because the statement holds for every kind of (unary and total) algebraic structure.

Comment: That is the reason why in lots of books they define isomorphisms as bijective homomorphism , whatever the underlying structure is. @ponchan